# How do I make a subset that has conditional requirements to a specific category in a column?

Tags: r

I am trying to create a  subset that will remove observations that have an if type of condition in them. I have a Region variable and Shutdown variable. Regions occur multiple times and some regions have no shutdowns in them. I want to remove all entries from a region with no shutdown, but keep all observations for a region if they have any at least one shutdown in the region (regardless if it has observations that have none).

Below is a sample of the dataset.

```
DT <- data.table(event = c(1:10),
                 Country = c("India","India","India","Pakistan","Pakistan", "Cameroon", "India","India","India","India"),
                 Region = c('Kashmir', 'Kashmir', 'Punjab', 'FATA', 'FATA', 'Nord-Ouest', "Rajasthan", 'Goa', 'Goa', 'Odisha'),
                 Demonstration = c(4,2,0,1,4,1,0, 1, 1, 2 ),
                 Shutdown = c(1,0,3,4,0,2,1, 0,0,0 ))

event  Country     Region Demonstration Shutdown
     1    India    Kashmir             4        1
     2    India    Kashmir             2        0
     3    India     Punjab             0        3
     4 Pakistan       FATA             1        4
     5 Pakistan       FATA             4        0
     6 Cameroon Nord-Ouest             1        2
     7    India  Rajasthan             0        1
     8    India        Goa             1        0
     9    India        Goa             1        0
    10    India     Odisha             2        0
```

My problem is when I can only figure out how to remove (via subsetting) all observations without a shutdown. But, I need to keep all observations a particular region, even if they don't all have a shutdown. What I want is for the subset to end up with a table that looks like the following and notice how 
both Kashmir and FATA are kept, but Goa and Odisha are eliminated.

```
     event  Country  Region    Demonstration Shutdown
     1    India    Kashmir             4        1
     2    India    Kashmir             2        0
     3    India     Punjab             0        3
     4 Pakistan       FATA             1        4
     5 Pakistan       FATA             4        0
     6 Cameroon Nord-Ouest             1        2
     7    India  Rajasthan             0        1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option is to check whether there are `any` elements in 'Shutdown' not equal to 0, by 'Region' to subset the Data.table (`.SD`0

```
DT[, .SD[any(Shutdown != 0)], Region]
#.      Region event  Country Demonstration Shutdown
#1:    Kashmir     1    India             4        1
#2:    Kashmir     2    India             2        0
#3:     Punjab     3    India             0        3
#4:       FATA     4 Pakistan             1        4
#5:       FATA     5 Pakistan             4        0
#6: Nord-Ouest     6 Cameroon             1        2
#7:  Rajasthan     7    India             0        1
```

Or with `.I` to return in the same column order

```
DT[DT[, .I[any(Shutdown != 0)], Region]$V1]
#.  event  Country     Region Demonstration Shutdown
#1:     1    India    Kashmir             4        1
#2:     2    India    Kashmir             2        0
#3:     3    India     Punjab             0        3
#4:     4 Pakistan       FATA             1        4
#5:     5 Pakistan       FATA             4        0
#6:     6 Cameroon Nord-Ouest             1        2
#7:     7    India  Rajasthan             0        1
```